# Feature Extraction: Dense SURFs, PCA-whitening, Improved Fisher Vectors & GMMs

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement the classifier discussed in this [paper](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/datasets/food-101/).  I've implemented everything apart from the feature extraction.  In section 5.1, the author(s) writes:

> "For each superpixel, two feature types are extracted: Dense surfs  which are transformed using signed squarerooting and L*a*b color values. In our experiments it has proved beneficial to also extract features  around the superpixels namely within its bounding box, to include more context. **Both surf and color values are encoded using Improved Fisher Vectors** as implemented in VlFeat and a **gmm with 64 modes**. We perform **pca-whitening on both feature channels**. In the end the two encoded feature vectors are concatenated, producing a dense vector with **8’576 values**."

There are a lot of things going on here, and I am confused in what order I should be performing the steps, as well as on which portion of the data set.

Here's my interpretation, in pseudo python:

```
def getFeatures(images):
    surfs_arr = []
    colors_arr = []
    for image in images:
        superpixels = findSuperpixels
        for superpixel in superpixels:
            box = boundingBox(superpixel)
            surfs = findDenseSURFs(box)
            colors = findColorValues(box)
            surfs_arr.append(surfs)
            colors_arr.append(colors)

    surfs_sample = (randomly choose X samples from surfs_arr)
    colors_sample = (randomly choose Y samples from colors_arr) #or histogram?

    # gmm has covariances, means properties
    gmm_surf = GMM(modes=64, surfs_sample)
    gmm_color = GMM(modes=64, colors_sample)

    surfs_as_fisher_vectors = IFV(gmm_surf, surfs_arr) 
    colors_as_fisher_vectors = IFV(gmm_color, color_arr)

    pca_surfs = PCA(ifv_surfs, whiten, n_components = 64)
    pca_colors = PCA(ifv_colors, whiten, n_components = 64

    features = concatenate((pca_surfs, pca_colors), axis=1)
    return features
```

my questions:

i. should PCA-whitening be performed prior to creating the GMMs? (like in this [example](http://yael.gforge.inria.fr/tutorial/tuto_imgindexing.html))

ii. Should i remove the surfs_sample and colors_sample sets from
    surfs_arr and colors_arr, respectively, before they are encoded as
    Fisher Vectors?

iii. As far as describing color values, is it best to leave them as is or
    create a histogram?

iv. The author states that he uses Dense SURFs, but makes no mention of
    how dense.  Do you recommend a particular starting point? 4x4,
    16x16?  Am I misunderstanding this?

v. Any idea where the author comes up with "a dense vector with 8,576
    values"?  To get a consistent number of features w/ different size
    superpixels, it seems to me that he must be

1) using a histogram to represent the color values, and either

2a) resizing each superpixel, or

2b) changing the density of his SURF grid.

I'm working in python w/ numpy, opencv, scikit-learn, mahotas, and a fisher vector [implementation](https://github.com/jacobgil/pyfishervector) ported from VLFeat.

Thanks.